# maintenance page / toolbar in Jboss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

Is there are simple way how to show maintenance toolbar or page e.g. 5 min before Jboss restart ? We have tens of various Java EE applications deployed in Jboss - would be great if we could inform users about maintenance / shutdown globally (we don't want to implement such functionality in each Java app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an app called "AppNotifier" that does exactly what you need.

You can fork it there : https://github.com/awillemant/app-notifier (sorry, GUI is in French for the moment).

There is 2 webapps :

- an administration app which allows you to configure many notifications for many applications
- a "public" application that provides notifications to client applications.

How it works :

1. In the administration interface, you declare your client application
2. Once it's done,  a unique key is generated and you can add several notifications with different levels and "time borders"
3. When you are in the screen that manage the notifications for a given client app, there is a button named "code d'integration". Click on it, it will show you a modal with a javascript snippet that you need to paste in your HTML header
4. That's it ! the snippet will load a script which will poll the "public" application for notifications and show them as a banner
   in the bottom of your screen.

I'll let you check the code and understand the other functionnalities.

If you have any questions, do not hesitate to ask ;)

Have a nice day.

Amaury